# How to adjust items under UITextView after resizing?

Tags: objective-c

Hi this is the method I use to increase the height of my UITextview:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
   CGRect frame = textView.frame;
   frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height;
   textView.frame = frame;
}
```

This is working, the problem is that after resizing the textview how I can properly adjust all the items under my UITextView?

Th structure is like follow:
     view
     --ScrollView
     ----TextView
     ----buton (after Rezising textview move this element too)
     ----TextField (after Rezising textview move this element too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is that you might want to make the UIButton and UITextField to be properties of the view controller so that you can access them and change their frame property inside the textViewDidChange method.

For example, in the .h file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button; //if you are using IB
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField; //do not forget to link these two in the IB
```

And in the .m file:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
   CGRect frame = textView.frame;
   frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height;
   textView.frame = frame;

   self.button.frame = CGRectMake(updatedButtonFrame);
   self.textField.frame = CGRectMake(updatedTextFieldFrame);
}
```